# How to style Flipview as inline-block?

Tags: html, css, win-universal-app, winjs, uwp

I can't style WinJS.UI.Flipview control. I can add rule to my CSS

```
display: inline-block
```

but Flipview just hiding and that's all... Tried many **display** modes but nothing solved my problem.

[That's how it looks with **display: block** and specified **width**, but with **display: inline-block** it's hiding! Other blocks have **inline-block** value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8XKD.png)

I'm using WinJS 4.4 and making Windows 8.1/WP 8.1 app. I want FlipView to stop hiding with inline-block value.

Comment: Can you show us it on JSfiddle.

Comment: @Guru Still can't make jsfiddle to show flipView correctly... It seems that WinJS works but can't process elements: https://jsfiddle.net/KenyaWest/v9ogebcb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Use display: inline-block and width as both!

```
display: inline-block;
width: 250px;
```